# How do I display the sum of the elements of myArray using nested enhanced for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have created a program for an assignment that requires me to display the elements of an array using nested enhanced for loops.

I get the error that it cannot convert from element type Integer[] to int.

`myArray` was already instantiated and initialized correctly in a constructor. I know that it's correct because I can display the elements of the array in list format just fine, from 1 to 60.

```
public void displayArrayProduct() {

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    decimalFormat.setGroupingSize(3);

    int p=1;

    System.out.print("The product of all element of myArray is ");
    for (int a : myArray) {
        for (int b : myArray) {
             p = p + myArray[a][b];

        }
    }
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(p));
}

}
```

What I expected this to do was output the sum of all of the elements of the array. I tried the exact same thing with regular for loops, and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately when I swapped to enhanced for loops, it stopped working, giving me the error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Integer[] to int

This is what my constructor looks like:

ExerciseTwo() {

```
    myArray = new Integer[6][10];

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            this.myArray[i][j] = i + 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: My original answer was posted before it was clear myArray is a multidimensional array. Given that, I agree with Vecna - who also correctly pointed out that using the for-each loop would allow you to get the integer itself instead of referencing it by index.

Original answer:
It looks like you may have changed something else when you converted the for loops.

The expression myArray[a][b] would be valid if myArray were a multi-dimensional array. The problem is that you are attempting to access a two-dimensional array, when the array itself is one-dimensional.

If you are attempting to multiply the entries at a and b, you'd need to do this:

```
p = p + myArray[a] * myArray[b];
```

or in shorthand:

```
p += myArray[a] * myArray[b];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int[] a : myArray) {
    for (int b : a) {
         p = p + b;

    }
}
```

Well the issue is a is an int array and not just an int.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [for-each loops](https://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop) which go through each element in an array or collection. So the thing you define in the loop declaration is an **element** from the array, rather than an **index**. Since you're using a 2-dimensional array (an array of arrays), each element in myArray is an integer **array**, so the first loop should be declared:

```
for (int[] a : myArray) {
```

So each **a** value will be of type int[], and what you want next is to get each integer from each of those integer arrays:

```
for (int b : a) {
```

Note that you're getting each integer in a, not in myArray. Now you can reference each integer in the array as just b, not an array's value at index b:

```
p = p + b;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like myArray is an array of arrays, not an array of ints.  Maybe this is more what you need?

```
    for (int[] a: myArray) {
        for (int b: a) {
            p = p + b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and I initialized it wrong in my constructor then.

Comment: I added my constructor code at the bottom of the question. Would you possibly be able to review it?

Comment: It looks fine.  This line here "myArray = new Integer[6][10];" is creating myArray as a two dimensional array, otherwise known as an array of arrays.  So you can think of it as one array where each element inside of it is an int[] type.

Comment: Since you are initializing using "new Integer" you will likely have to change the for loop to use Integer[] instead of int[]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you had 60 elements in your Array, so I simply created a sample 2 x 30 Array as an example:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[2][30];
    int increment = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < myArray[x].length; y++) {
            myArray[x][y] = increment;
            increment++;
        }
    }
```

Next, if you are using a for-each loop, your error is occurring because each individual row of the Array as an INDEX IN IT OF ITSELF. So your for-each loop should represent be of the type (int[]) an int Array:

```
for(int[] x: myArray) {
```

Within each individual Array (x) there is an int primitive value so we run another for-each-loop in order to extract each individual value:

for(int y: x) {

And here is your complete code:

```
for(int[] x: myArray) {
        for(int y: x) {
            totalVal += y;
        }
    }
System.out.println(totalVal);
```

And the output is the sum of each int in the Array:

```
1770
```